# How to access a String in nested &Box?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let a = &Box::new(&Box::new(String::from("Rust")));
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of "Rust" but unable to do that. When I try `let b  = &***a;` I get a compile error `"temporary value dropped while borrowed"`.

Comment: I think the error is not in the initialization of `b` but in how you build `a`: it is a reference to a boxed reference to a temporary, but what is the lifetime of those temporaries?

Comment: The compiler error [*literally tells you exactly how to fix your code*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c8939bcc552d3d6d201e6b286c1dd47f). Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your example a bit to get a more clear error message:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(&String::from("Rust"));
    let b  = &**a;
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

```rust
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     let a = Box::new(&String::from("Rust"));
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                       |
  |                       creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
3 |     let b  = &**a;
  |              ---- borrow later used here
  |
```

As you can see from the error, the lifetime of temporary objects **that are not bound to a variable** ends after the current statement, and therefore those temporaries cannot be accessed from subsequent statements.

---

To fix your example, you have to make the temporaries live long enough, for example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a1 = Box::new(String::from("Rust"));
    let a2 = Box::new(&a1);
    let a = &a2;
    let b  = &**a;
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`String` creates an owned variable (stored on heap). So when you wrote `String::from("Rust")` which you passed it to `Box` smart pointer (which moves value from stack to heap, but in this case it won't).

You are also using `Box<T>` incorrectly, which is a smart pointer, but you are dereferencing it, losing its ownership.

Instead you could do:

```rust
let h = String::from("Hello");
let a: Box<Box<String>> = Box::new(Box::new(h));
println!("{}", &***a);
>>> "Hello"
```

Better solution is instead suggested by compiler:

```rust
// help: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
let binding = Box::new(String::from("Rust"));
let a = &Box::new(&binding);
```

Comment: You don't need to convert *everything* to owned to make this work, and it may not be suitable for OP's purpose to do so. All you need to do (and the compiler literally hands a solution when fed OP's code) is create a let binding for the first Box.